Как добавить отношения «многие-ко-многим» между таблицами из разных баз данных?
Пишу пет-проект интернет-магазин на голанг. Разбил монолитную архитектуру на микросервисную и для каждого микросервиса использую отдельную БД postgres.
У меня есть два микросервиса: микросервис продуктов и микросервис категорий
Таблицы для них выглядят так:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

create table if not exists products
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);
create table categories
(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null,
    slug text not null,
    created_at timestamp not null default now(),
    updated_at timestamp
);

Как я могу добавить поле категория в таблицу продукта, если они находятся в разных базах данных? Есть ли такая возможность, либо эти таблицы должны быть в одной базе данных? Могу ли я просто добавить массив category_ids number в бд без какой-либо связи, не считается ли это костыльным решением?

Костыльным решением считается разделить категории и продукты на разные микросервисы. И затем доблестно преодолевать сложности, которых бы не было.
